# What is the next permutation of 1342?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

How to find the next larger permutation 1342 in lexicographic order? I followed the algorithm in [Next Permutation Algorithm based on Lexicographic ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622532/algorithm-to-find-next-greater-permutation-of-a-given-string) and I found 2134. But we know that after 1342 the next larger permutation in fact is 1423, isn't it?

Comment: And the standard algorithm, as described in your link,  yields $1423$ as it should.  Following the notation in the quote from Wikipedia, $i=2,j=3$.  Then follow the steps as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the algorithm given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622539/7450338) on $1342$, and using the dreaded 1-indexing to correspond with natural language "$1$st digit, $2$nd digit" etc.:

1. Find the largest $i$ such that the $i$th digit is less than the $(i+1)$st digit: this is $i=2$ (as $3<4$ but $4>2$).
2. Find the largest $j>2$ such that the $j$th digit is larger than the $2$nd digit: this is $j=3$ (as $3<4$ but $3>2$).
3. Swap the $2$nd and $3$rd digit: $1432$.
4. Reverse the order of all digits from $2$nd onwards (not including $2$nd): $1423$.

This produces $1423$ as expected.